# How to install GDAL 2.1.3 using virtualenv (Python 2.7) under Windows 10?

Tags: python, gdal

I use Windows 10, have Python 2.7 installed as part of ArcGIS 10.5. I have installed GDAL using a package manager that runs fine in Python, meaning I can import both gdal and ogr in a Python editor. But when I try to install it using virtualenv, things don´t work - I can´t install GDAL properly. I have tried various other solutions, such as specifying the GDAL version, but I cannot install GDAL using virtualenv. How can I install it using virtualenv?

```
(venv) C:\Home\venv\Scripts>pip install gdal
Collecting gdal
  Using cached GDAL-2.1.3.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: gdal
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gdal ... error
  Complete output from command c:\home\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\eric\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ox37ve\\gdal\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\eric\appdata\local\temp\tmpfydmk9pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7
  copying gdal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
  copying ogr.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
  copying osr.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
  copying gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
  copying gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo
  running build_ext
  building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\extensions
  C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -IC:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\include -Ic:\home\venv\PC -Ic:\home\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include /Tpextensions/gdal_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\extensions/gdal_wrap.obj
  gdal_wrap.cpp
  C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
  extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3085) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Eric\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Download GDAL‑2.1.3‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl from Christoph Gohlke's [unnofficial python packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) for Windows.

```
pip install path\to\GDAL‑2.1.3‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
```

Comment: I have downloaded a wheel file form Cristoph's repo and was successful using pip installing it on the system, but failed to install the wheel in the virtualenv.